# Install React + TypeScript using Vite error : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, vite

I just installed React + TypeScript, after all the processes have been carried out successfully and when I want to run React in the browser it appears like this:

[image]

Why is this? i am using node v14

Comment: Check your node version and your NVM version -- Make sure they are both up-to-date  ...   If you are using node v14 I believe you need to be on NVM 16.x.x --  `nvm ls` Then 
`nvm use 16.x.x`